# How do "frozen fresh" herbs compare to fresh?

Tags: freezing, herbs, fresh

I noticed my grocery store has "frozen fresh" chopped herbs (basil, cilantro, oregano I think, among others) in the freezer section. How would these compare to fresh herbs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The texture of frozen herbs is going to be totally different after thawing.  In my opinion frozen herbs are fine for using in cooking, but they don't work well as a garnish or as an addition to a dish at the end of cooking.

The taste is definitely better than dried, though.

Comment: Right, and many herbs will turn black as they thaw, which is fine if they're in a stew or something, but terrible as garnish!

Comment: Agree with this they are better than dried and especially good as the winter comes up as fresh becomes very expensive. Frozen herbs are perfect in soups, stocks and casseroles.